# When intergrating Active Storage and Google Cloud Storage, is the "project" key in storage.yml really necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

Below is an example of GCS settings in `storage.yml`:

```
google:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/keyfile.json") %>
  project: ""
  bucket: ""
```

Since there is already `project_id` inside `credentials`, what is the purpose of `project`? Does this make any difference if I omit this key?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a requirement from Active Storage as mentioned [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service). Most likely, both parameters are needed due to the fact that you could create a service account in one project, and give it access to a different one. If you did this, the credentials of the service account would have the origin project, however, you could access the second project with the same file.